# How to set custom value for row_total column of sales_flat_quote_item table in magento

Tags: magento

I am trying to add a product in cart that has base price of $25.When I entered 3 quantities of that product the row_total becomes $75, but I want to give 2 quantities of that product to be free i.e. price $0. So my row_total will be like $75-($25*2)=$25. So how can I add this custom value in row_total column of "sales_flat_quote_item", so that it saves row total to be $25 but not $75?

Comment: Have you tried using an observer on an event that fires around the time of the purchase?

Comment: yes, I am trying adding the custom values in observer but it is not able to change the "row_total" column. Even if I change the column values forcefuly by using the model object, it still saves the data by multiplying the quantity. Following is the code I am using in observer for setting the custom values.


$quoteItem = $observer->getQuoteItem();
$quoteItem->setOriginalCustomPrice($sub_total);
$quoteItem->setRowTotal($quote_row_total);